# Azure Static Outbound Private IP

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-network, azure-container-apps

I've the following scenario:

- There's a VNET which has a few services (Azure Container Apps + Azure Functions) which are internal services (do not acccept any external traffic). This VNET is connected to On-Prem using ExpressRoute. There's a service (API) hosted On-Prem, which we want to call from ContainerApps/Functions that is only accessible internally. This service is behind firewall. The administrators of this On-Prem service wants us to provide the private IP(s) of the services which will call the On-Prem service - the important part is that we want this IP(s) to be static, so we do not need to change any firewall settings frequently. As far as I know, there's no way to control the private IP of neither ContainerApp nor Azure Function. I've considered Azure NAT Gateway, but it seems to be only working with public IP(s).
  Are there any other alternatives ?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the latest [specification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.app/managedenvironments?pivots=deployment-language-bicep) (api-version=2022-06-01-preview), it supposed to be possible.

In the `vnetConfiguration` block, you can specify the outbound type and the virtual applicance IP:

```bicep
vnetConfiguration: {
  ...
  outboundSettings: {
    outBoundType: 'UserDefinedRouting'
    virtualNetworkApplianceIp: 'X.X.X.X' 
  }
}
```

This required a `Premium` sku:

```bicep
sku: {
  name: 'Premium'
}
```

Found also this interesting article about locking down the VNET:

- [Lock down VNET with Network Security Groups and Firewall](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-container-apps/wiki/Lock-down-VNET-with-Network-Security-Groups-and-Firewall)

Comment: Thanks a lot. 
It's interesting, because I cannot find any information about the premium tier of Azure Container Apps. It seems it's not available yet - when I try to create a Managed Env with Premium SKU, I get  PremiumManagedEnvironmentCreationNotEnabled. I am going to open a ticket in Github.

Comment: @macpak I had a chat with MS and still private preview so you will have to request access to the preview.